# Teradata - Finding Rows with Special Placeholder Characters

Tags: unicode, database-design, character-encoding, teradata

I have a table in Teradata that accumulates products from multiple sources, and puts them into one big table.  Some of those sources were set up with a UTF-8 source, but a Latin encoding on their target.  This caused some records to insert with black diamonds with white question marks in them.  The table I am consolidating them into is UNICODE, but I want to be able to flag rows that contain these placeholder characters.  I've tried Unicode to Latin functions, but that also reacts to legitimate Non-Latin Unicode characters (like foreign languages).

[These are the characters I'm after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpIOA.png)

Is there any way I can identify and tag records that contain this specific placeholder character?  Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `CHAR2HEXINT` function to verify, but that appears to be the Error Substitution character (x'1A' Latin or U+FFFD Unicode). The trick to finding that specific value is generating the comparison value.

```
POSITION(CHR(26) IN Latin_Column) > 0
```

or

```
POSITION(TRANSLATE(CHR(26) USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE WITH ERROR) IN Unicode_Column) > 0
```

Comment: Follow up question, do you know how to get rid of them?  Both OReplace and OTranslate throw a "Untranslatable Character" error.

Comment: Should work against a Unicode field using `TRANSLATE(CHR(26) USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE WITH ERROR)` as the string to be changed. For a Latin field the trick is that all the arguments must be Unicode or all Latin (because otherwise there will be implicit translation to Unicode which will faill). So either explicitly `TRANSLATE Latin_column USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE WITH ERROR)` as the input string and search for that value, or explicitly `TRANSLATE('String_Literal' USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN)` for any literal values supplied as arguments - since literals are Unicode - and search for CHR(26)..